# TabBarController item's Content not sized to screen size

Tags: ios, iphone, uikit, uitabbarcontroller, xcode-storyboard

I am having an issue with the size of the tab bar items when loaded. The home view loads fine in the right size (it's a tableview) but any subsequent views are not being sized to the screen size and i can't figure out why and what setting i need to change. I used the same process to add the other controllers in storyboard but nothing i do is letting the content size to the size of the screen. I am having this issue with all the items except the first tab bar.

It won't align any control correctly like the segmented control in the screenshot attached in other tab items.

Please help

Please see attached images:

P.S: I am just learning how to develop an iphone app.

[image: The first tab bar item. Content is sized to screen size]
[image: The second tab bar item. Content is NOT sized to screen size]

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is. Is it just the segmented control not being place correctly? Are you using auto layout?

Comment: @rdelmar it's every other view other than the first view controller (Home). Every other view is skewed in display. I have auto layout selected and sizing class selected as well

Comment: Can you share the constraints that you have set for the "Home Again" view(Constraints for the tableview cells and the segmented control)?

Comment: You need to add constraints to views from your storyboard. Check this link out.https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: There are no constraints on any of my scenes right now. Not on the home scene either. it has been the defaults so far. Do i need to set any values or checkboxes to match things up? suggestions?  @Vijayts

Comment: @ErsinSezgin ha...off to read. thanks for the link

Comment: @user3821501 no problem, you HAVE TO put constraints to prevent these kind of problems. Further, I suggest you to read documentations about any topic that you have problem until you understand the logic.

Comment: @ErsinSezgin Yea...i read on autolayout and now have my scenes and controls the way i want them!!! Yea...i didn't know it was an autolayout issue initially. #stillLearning

Comment: @user3821501 Exactly why I asked you for the constraints :) Glad you solved it.

Comment: @Vijayts Yea i see now :) Thanks for your help and Happy New Year!! :)